# Windows: ssh: connect to host (machine name) port 22: Connection refused

Tags: windows, ssh

I am using my Windows 10 Home edition PC and having opened my command prompt with administrators privileges, I run the command;

```
ssh user@machine
```

and I get the error message;

> ssh: connect to host (machine name) port 22: Connection refused

I have attempted to unblock port 22 via the Windows Defender Firewall settings, and creating inbound and outbound rules that will keep port 22 open. But this has no effect. I want to connect my PC with AWS via SSH. So how do I fix this?

Comment: you need to enable SSH and allow it through the firewall on the AWS system. you should not need to change the firewall on the windows PC to make this work. you do not need TCP\22 open on the windows system, only on the AWS system. since you do not have an SSH server on the windows PC on port 22, allowing 22 on the firewall will do nothing. Applications "open" and "close" ports; Firewalls just allow or deny them. allowing a port that is closed because no application has opened it will have no effect.

Comment: Thank you for that, you answered my question perfectly! I have now connected with AWS.

Comment: Question is unclear.  You are trying to `ssh user@machine` but your problem is connecting your `PC with AWS`?  Please edit your question so we can better understand your problem.

Comment: @Frank Thomas answered my question with his comment. I understand what I am doing better now.